# MySQL Replication: multi-host connectionString vs Load Balancer

Tags: mysql, connection-string, load-balancing, replication

I have 2 MySQL servers (on 2 different machines). I have setup a master/slave replication using GTID.

I am not sure how should I connect my web server to the DB.

According to [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/multiple-servers/), I can use the following connectionString:

```
Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2, serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

At the same time, I have come across articles about MySQL load balancing, like  [HAProxy](https://severalnines.com/resources/tutorials/mysql-load-balancing-haproxy-tutorial).

The connectionString option seems really simple and I am tempted to use that, but I am not aware if there is any limitations/drawbacks to it?

What is the benefit of using a load balancer?